# Upgrade of dell laptop screen size from 14'' to 15''

Tags: laptop, display

I have [Dell Inspiron n4110](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/inspiron-14r-n4110/drivers), it is having 14” screen. Can I upgrade the size to 15” (Inspiron n5110) screen keeping my other things like my hard disk and ram intact.

If required I can also change my bottom box as well, but is it possible to replace Dell Inspiron n4110 screen with Dell Inspiron n5110 screen?

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to swap screens? Why not just get a new computer? Do you like something in particular about your `n4110` (such as the keyboard, case design, sentimental value), or is it what is loaded on the computer (such as the OS, software), or is this budget minded?

Comment: @tehDorf sentimental.. its gifted so dont want to replace the entire thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that it *might* actually be technically possible to replace the lid with the LCD.  However, the number of hurdles in your way are many.  Do they use the same chassis and housing?  Does the connector cable have the same pinouts and length required?  Is the power supplied to the LCD meet match the requirements?  Does it use the same latching mechanism?  The list goes on and on.

Answer (score 3):

**Practically speaking, no.**

Your first issue would be just the physical size difference of the screens/lids. The [n4110](http://www.pcworld.com/product/1289190/dell-inspiron-14r-n4110-notebook.html) is 13.5" wide, compared to the [n5110](http://www.dell.com/ae/p/inspiron-15r-n5110/pd) which is 14.80". Replacing the lid would result in an overhang around the base, which could cause the screen to be damaged from the base. Also changing the lids would probably need to have the exact same dimensions for the lid hinge for this to be possible.

If you were to try to take the lid apart and replace the LCD pane itself, you would also run into physical dimension issues - the n4110's bezel would be too small which would hide the edges of the larger LCD panel (assuming you were able to mount it securely).

**A practical option might be to repurpose your current laptop -** [There are plenty of uses for a laptop with a broken screen.](http://lifehacker.com/top-10-ways-to-repurpose-your-old-laptop-1522986846)

- [You could turn it into a media center](http://www.instructables.com/id/Old-laptop-Media-Center-XBMC/) by connecting it to your TV. There are plenty of examples of this, and it would probably be my first choice.
- [You could turn it into a home server](http://lifehacker.com/5957558/turn-a-broken-laptop-motherboard-into-a-silent-home-server) - This would enable you to access files remotely, serve up a low-bandwidth website, or possibly even do some home automation task such as a web cam for security, or turn your lights on/off or open/close your garage door.

These are just a couple of ideas to get your head rolling. Depending on how much work you want to put into it, there is a whole number of different options for you to repurpose your laptop. I think converting it into something else would make it that much more special to me - I still have my first computer I built in 2004 sitting in the corner serving up videos and music!

Oh, one last thing. If you go the media center route, check out Logitec's [Touch Mouse Server](http://www.logitech.com/touchmouse) - you can use your smart phone as a wireless touchpad/keyboard if you want to put your laptop in an out-of-the-way place and don't want to run cables.

Comment: thanks but can i know why and isnt there any way that i can get this done?

Comment: @lalitkumar The answer to "Can it be done?" is almost always "Yes", but the next question is "How much will it cost?", which can get impractically high quickly. There are many issues to swapping monitors on a laptop, but perhaps you could explain what the problem is you are having and we might be able to suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: the screen in my 14' laptop has been damaged and i want a bigger screen.

Comment: @lalitkumar I've updated my answer with some options

Comment: @tehDurf thank u so very mch for your kind help.. :)